# SQL how to handle a many to many relationship

Tags: sql, database, many-to-many, relationship

I have two tables that have a many-many relationship:

```
Player(personID, school)
Team(teamID, name)
```

What code would I use to create the associative entity table called playerTeam.

I have tried the following:

```
CREATE TABLE
(
playerID INT NOT NULL, 
teamID INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(playerID, teamID)
);
```

I do not know how to connect up the tables in this instance.

Comment: You should also indicate which database you're using. SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle may be...

Comment: Create a foreign key constraint on the table based on the database of you are using.

Comment: my apologies added database type to title

Comment: You should have a look at "pivot tables". You need to create a third table and add two 1-to-many relationships.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE teamPlayer
(
playerID INT NOT NULL, 
teamID INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(playerID, teamID)
);

alter table teamPlayer
add constraint 
    fk_teamPlayer__Player foreign key(playerID) references Player(personID);

alter table teamPlayer
add constraint 
    fk_teamPlayer__Team foreign key(teamID) references Team(teamID);
```

Or this:

```
CREATE TABLE teamPlayer
(
playerID INT NOT NULL, 
teamID INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(playerID, teamID),

constraint fk_teamPlayer__Player
foreign key(playerID) references Player(personID),

constraint fk_teamPlayer__Team 
foreign key(teamID) references Team(teamID)

);
```

If you don't need to name your foreign keys explicitly, you can use this:

```
CREATE TABLE teamPlayer
(
playerID INT NOT NULL references Player(personID), 
teamID INT NOT NULL references Team(teamID),
PRIMARY KEY(playerID, teamID)
);
```

---

All major RDBMS pretty much complied with ANSI SQL on relationship DDL. Everyone is identical

CREATE THEN ALTER(explicitly named foreign key):

- Postgresql: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/0a096
- MySQL: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a096
- Oracle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0a096
- SQL Server: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0a096

CREATE(explicitly named foreign key):

- Postgresql: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/46ebb
- MySQL: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46ebb
- Oracle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46ebb
- SQL Server: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46ebb

CREATE(auto-named foreign key):

- Postgresql: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/82742
- MySQL: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82742
- Oracle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/82742
- Sql Server: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82742

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify a kind of a relationship when you create the table, unless you're using FOREIGN KEY.
In your case you're actually missing table name in your query, it should be like that

```
CREATE TABLE `playerTeam`
(
`playerID` INT NOT NULL, 
`teamID` INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`playerID`, `teamID`)
);
```

Comment: This is not quite true. It depends on which database engine is being used and then what storage engine is being used. You could link them using foreign keys.

Comment: That is not correct.  Foreign key relationships have to exist as well to ensure that you have a constraint based table as well.  Definitely create foreign keys.